# checkbox updated in realtime to table in DB

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Was using a repeater to display a list on screen.  For each record I added a `<asp:checkbox`, which I would like updated in real time to the corresponding table in the DB, depending on whether or not it was clicked.....So far I got: (Using JS)
ASPX:

```
<th style="width:200px;"><asp:CheckBox Name='<%# CallUtilityChangeId((int)Eval("id")) %>' runat="server" 
onclick='UtilityChanged(<%#((int)Eval("id"))%>);'
Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Checked")) %>'/></th>  
<th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Comment") %></th>
```

C#

```
 protected string CallUtilityChangeId(int id)
    {
        return "Utilitychanged('" + id.ToString() + "');";
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
 function UtilityChanged(id) {
                    userId = userIdentifier;                     
                }
```

The source code returns:

```
<th style="width:200px;">
<span Name="Utilitychanged(&#39;55&#39;);">
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptSelectedUtilities_ctl01_ctl00" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptSelectedUtilities$ctl01$ctl00" onclick="UtilityChanged(&lt;%#((int)Eval(&quot;id&quot;))%>);" />
</span></th>  
<th style="width:200px;"></th>
```

Instead of onclick="UtilityChanged(<%#((int)Eval("id"))%>);" />
I need it to return UtilityChanged("71") for eg. just the identification no. of the id.

Comment: So you just need to get the 'ID' of the DB record that you are about to update and use it in some AJAX javascript function??--i want to know what your trying to do.

Comment: Hi Ebram, well...overall I would like the checkbox to be selected or deselected by the user, which updates the corresponding record in the DB, done in real time (without using page refresh).

Comment: @john in that case you need to use an updatepanel in conjunction with the repeater.

Comment: THe better way to do it is by using web service, also for the efficiency

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you want to have a checkbox in a repeater that has a server sided event, where you can get an ID value to use in a database command, all done asynchronously?  If so, you can use the update panels to do this.

First, you must wrap your repeater in an update panel and add a script manager:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" >                                                     
<ContentTemplate>
<!-- put repeater in here -->
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Next, you want to add a checkbox with a server event attached to it.  this gets added to the repeater row.  You also want to add a label that has the ID value.  In this example, its added by the data source

```
<ItemTemplate>                            
<tr  class="listcolor">                        
<td style="display:none;border-right:0px solid  #808080  ; border-bottom:0px solid #808080;">
<asp:CheckBox ID="myCB" Text="Approved" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="check_change"  /> 
</td>
<td style="display:none;border-right:0px solid  #808080  ; border-bottom:0px solid #808080;">
 <asp:label ID="userId" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "someId") %>'></asp:label>
</td>                              
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Now, add the check box event.  When a control posts back to the server, if its in a repeater, or similar control, you can cast sender to the object that caused the postback, then get its parent row, then find the label control:

```
Protected Sub check_change(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
     'first, cast the sender to a check box
     Dim cb As CheckBox = CType(sender, CheckBox)
     'then use that to find the label in its parent control ( the row its on)
     Dim userId As Label = CType(cb.Parent.FindControl("userId"), Label)
End Sub
```

That should do it.  If you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`(without using page refresh)` means using `Ajax`.

First you should understand how `.Net` server control is parsed into normal `HTML` tags.

Suppose your code is like this:

```
<asp:Repeater Id="rpt">
......
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server" Name="someName" Checked="true" />
....
</asp:Repeater>
```

it 'll be rendered like this:

```
<span name="someName">
    <input id="rpt_ctl00_chkBox" type="checkbox" name="rpt$ctl00$chkBox" checked="checked">
</span>
```

as you can notice there are 2 things here::

1. The checkbox is contained inside `<span>` tag.
2. The `ID` and `Name` properties of that checkbox is renamed by the `.Net` with something relative to the parent container(the Repeater) "`RepeaterId_ct100_CheckBoxId`".

Second thing if you want to get some value without been messed by the view engine or the `.Net` try to use custom attribute.

sorry for long introduction.

solution::

```
<input id="chkBox" runat="server" type="checkbox" checked='<%# Eval("Your_Record_ColumnName")%>' onchange="YourJavascriptFunctionName(this);return false;" columId='<%# Eval("Column_Id")%>'/>
```

Then by JavaScript or `jQuery` you get the value of that attribute.

```
function YourJavascriptFunctionName(chk)
{
    recordId = $(chk).attr("columId");
    //then use ajax to update the DB Table.
}
```

how to make ajax call that's another thing..tell me if you need help in it.